# JMeter Correlation with Parameters

Tags: jmeter

I am just new in JMeter and wanted to know if we can do simultaneous correlation and parameterization. I have the sample tag below

```
<option value="28964,532,29046">My Option</option>
```

So I want to correlate the value and at the same use the parameterized value for the My Option.

So I've been thinking of using the Regular Expression Extractor and got this on mind.

```
<option\svalue="(.+?)">${MyParameter}<\/option>
```

However when trying to run the script, the data from the csv data set was fetch correctly upon checking using post debug processor but it doesn't get the ${MyParameter} from when used together with Regular Expression Extractor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given correct JMeter configuration - CSV Data Set Config needs to be processed **before** Regular Expression Extractor there shouldn't be a problem to use CSV-originated variable in the Regular Expression

[image: CSV Data Set Config with Variable]

as an alternatives you can consider the following functions:

- [CSVRead](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)
- [StringFromFile](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile)

right in Regular Expression input like

```
<option\svalue="(.+?)">${__StringFromFile(/path/to/your/file.csv,,,)}<\/option>
```

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) articles series for detailed information on above and other useful JMeter functions.

Comment: Managed to have it working on my end.
Have used the same flow @Dmitri T

Thanks for the help, Cheers!